# Large Local Data Analysis: SQL Server Express vs MS Access

Tags: ms-access, sql-server-express, data-analysis

What is better for large, local data analysis; MS Access or SQL Server Express?

To paint the picture of my constraints/needs:

I do Cisco telephony analysis for a large corporation. I historically have imported data sets from TSQL into excel to manipulate the data locally. I do not have server space/rights to use our corporate SQL Servers for my work so everything must be done locally.

The analysis consists of merging several data sets together before beginning analysis. Each data set will typically contain 200k-900k records. Most analysis is adhoc and requirements change frequently.

Lately, my data sets have begun to exceed 1m rows and the Excel version I am supplied with is unable to support volume above 1.3m records. The processing time to merge several data sets this large is becoming excruciating. Simple functions like Index/Match take 15 minutes to complete.

I need to find a better way of performing analysis and cannot decide between MS Access and SQL Server Express.

My concern with Access is that it will not have the capacity for what I need and I am worried about database corruption.

My concern with SQL Server is that I am unsure of using it in this manner. I need to determine standard deviations, averages, counts, etc, based on aggregated data. I use SQL as an analyst (data retrieval) and have very little experience with creating/managing a SQL SQL Server database. I am also concerned with the creation time for adhoc reports. I am unsure if this is a valid concern.

Which one should I use in place of excel for my needs?

Comment: My vote goes to SQL Server, but your question is better posted at http://dba.stackexchange.com/. It's inappropriate for this site because it is primarily opinion-based.

Comment: Definitely use SQL Server - it's a real database - not just a file-based record manager.... and using things like the Reporting Services, you make do great reporting based on your data stored in a SQL Server database. And since version 2008, the size limit of the Express edition is **10 GB** which is quite generous .... **AND** it gives you (and your customers) the chance to provide the data as a SQL Server database - if your customer wants to attach it and analyze it further on their corporate SQL Servers later on

Answer (score 1):

If I were in your position I would use SQL Server Express Edition to store the data and perform the more complex data manipulation, and I would use Access with ODBC linked tables into the SQL Server database for "exploring", e.g.,

- creating ad-hoc queries to get a better understanding of the data, with the option of exporting those queries to Excel for further crunching, and
- building reports quickly without getting into the whole SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS) thing.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the maximum database size for Access is 1 GB. SQL Server Express is 10 GB. You'd want to use SQL Server for many other reasons as well. Access is an atavism - an evolutionary throwback.

Comment: The maximum size of an Access database *file* (and hence an Access table) is 2GB. It is possible to work with multiple (linked) tables in several .accdb (or .mdb) files, but when dealing with that much data it's probably time to seriously think about migrating the data to SQL Server (or similar) anyway.